# Determine extrema of a function $f$, what if the Hessian Matrix is not positive, negative or semi-definite? Do I need to calculate the Eigenvalues?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $P$ be a critical point of the function $f$ and the Hessian Matrix at this point be given by:

$$ H_{f}(P)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right) $$

I want to check if the function $f$ has an extreme point, so I calculated the determinants of the principal minors:

$$ \operatorname{det} 2=2, \quad \operatorname{det}\left(\begin{array}{cc}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)=-1, \quad \operatorname{det} H_{f}(P)=-3 $$

Therefore, according to (i) , $H_f$ is not positive, negative or semi-definite, so I cannot make a statement using the criterion (i).

Do I now have to calculate all eigenvalues (ii) in order to be able to say with certainty that $H_f$ is indefinite and there are no extreme values (edge points excluded for now)?

Important information:

(i)
Let $A=\left(a_{i, j}\right)_{i, j \in\{1, \ldots, n\}} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be symmetric.

1. $A$ is positive definite if and only if for each $k \in\{1, \ldots, n\}$, the $k$-th principal minor has a positive determinant.
2. $A$ is negative definite if and only if for each $ \in\{1, \ldots, n\}$, the sign of the determinant of the $k$-th principal minor is $(-1)^{k}$, meaning the determinants of the principal minors alternate between negative, positive, negative, positive, etc.
3. $A$ is semi-definite if and only if $\operatorname{det} A=0$.

(ii)
A symmetric real matrix is called positive [negative] definite if all its eigenvalues are positive [negative]. We call it positive [negative] semi-definite if zero is an eigenvalue and all other eigenvalues are positive [negative]. It is called indefinite if it has both positive and negative eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

Any hermitian matrix falls into one of the 3 cases ([Wikipedia - Definite Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_matrix#Eigenvalues)):

- Positive semi-definite
- Negative semi-definite
- Indefinite

And since you ruled out the first two cases, $H_f(P)$ must be indefinite.

Though one doesn't need this specific knowledge, just the 2nd necessary condition for local minima that says that for $x$ to be a minimum it has to be that $H_f(x)$ is positive semi-definite.

Via contraposition you therefore can exclude that $P$ is a local minimum, and similarly by checking $-f$ that $P$ is no local maximum. So $P$ has to be a saddle point.

Answer (score 1):

You actually know a lot about that Hessian matrix. I personally dislike these "characterization theorems" for critical points. It is better to remember their **proof**.

The Hessian matrix $H_f(P)$, as you call it, is symmetric; hence, there is a orthogonal matrix $O$ such that
$$
O^TH_f(P)O=\begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0&\lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3\end{bmatrix}, $$
Those conditions you found imply that:

1. None of the eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$ is zero (for otherwise $\det H_f(P)$ would be zero);
2. The eigenvalues change sign (for otherwise the matrix would be either positive or negative definite).

You already knew all this, actually. Now you ask: do I need to compute $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3$? No, you don't. You know 1. and 2. and that is enough; indeed, for a small vector $v\in\mathbb R^3$,
$$\begin{split}
f(P+v)- f(P)&= v^TH_f(P)v+ \text{remainder} \\ &\cong \lambda_1v_1^2+\lambda_2v_2^2+\lambda_3v_3^2+\text{remainder}.
\end{split}
$$
Here $\cong$ means that you have to perform a harmless orthogonal coordinate change. You see from here that you can make $f(P+v)-f(P)$ both strictly positive or strictly negative, by appropriately choosing $v$; for example, if $\lambda_1>0$, then choosing $v=(\epsilon, 0,0)$ results in $f(P+v)-f(P)>0$, provided $\epsilon$ is small enough, which allows you to disregard the remainder.

You conclude that the point is neither a maximum nor a minimum.